# Why can't I get the examples from the tutorials about multiprocessing to work in Python?

Tags: python-3.x, multiprocessing

I'm struggling with this code copied from a tutorial about multiprocessing:

(source: https://tutorialedge.net/post/python/python-multiprocessing-tutorial/ )

```
from multiprocessing import Process, Queue
import random

def rand_num():
    num = random.random()
    print(num)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    queue = Queue()

    processes = [Process(target=rand_num, args=()) for x in range(4)]

    for p in processes:
        p.start()

    for p in processes:
        p.join()
```

Testing in Python 3.6.1 on W7 pc.

In Idle it comes back to the prompt without printing the expected numbers.

When doubleclicked in Windows the py.exe screen comes up for a very short time and closes again.

Can anybody tell me where it goes wrong?

Comment: When executing in `IDLE` your condition (multiprocess guard) doesn't resolve as `True`. When executing as a script it works, but it takes a split second to finish. Don't execute by double-clicking, instead open your `Command Prompt` and use: `python your_script_name.py` . Alternatively, you can add some random delay to your `rand_num()` process (e.g. `time.sleep(0.5 + random.random()*3)`, don't forget to `import time` first) if you want to prolong your process execution.

Comment: yes, that's it! Problem solved. Thanks!